# Unity fails to connect to Holographic Remoting Player App on HoloLens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, openxr

I have a MRTK 3 project which I want to view in the Holographic Remoting app installed on a HoloLens 2. However, when I press play in Unity, the error message "Cannot establish a connection to Holographic Remoting Player on target with IP Address xxx" is shown and the program shuts down again [Error Message in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlBzA.png).

Did anyone had the same issue before or understands what this error message actually means and why it cannot establish the connection?

I have Unity Version 2021.3.19f1, the latest Holographic Remoting version, OpenXR Plugin 1.6, Visual Studio 2022 and my OpenXR settings are as proposed in the MRTK 3 documentation.

The IP address I enter is the one shown in the app and I tried to connect to two different company networks as well as via USB and creating a hotspot with a mobile phone but nothing worked. Strangely enough, it did connect once (the waiting time was also a less shorter about 20s as opposed to the usual 1min when the connection cannot be established), but when pressing play to stop the program and pressing play again, I could not recreate the working scenario. I have the feeling that the loading time of 1min is much longer than it should be and that because of it, there might be simply a timeout from the Holographic Remoting app after a while.

What is working though is to access the device through the Windows Device Portal. Just with Unity, I had no success.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Comment: Thank you for your reminder! I will keep it in mind for the future.